# Node setMouseTransparent Exceptions

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, vbox

If I have a VBox with 3 buttons and make the VBox mouse transparent, how can I ensure that its children won't be made transparent? I need the buttons to be clickable.

I'm trying to make a clock, and my solution so far is to have a StackPane. Add 12 VBoxes in the StackPane, make it as large as the StackPane, and rotate it around the center axis 30 degrees * n. Unfortunately, the VBoxes block the layers beneath it all the way up to the top of the StackPane.

Comment: Mouse transparent will affect also its children. Maybe [`setPickOnBounds`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setPickOnBounds-boolean-) can help you.

Comment: Why do you want to make it mouse transparent? Mouse events should propagate through to the `StackPane` anyway.

Comment: Because I have 12 Vboxes that are rotated about the center, 30 degrees each. They overlap each other on opposite ends, and block input on half of the VBoxes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to set each VBox's pickOnBounds property to false. Since a VBox is really a blank container with no geometric shape, disabling the pick on bounds renders the VBox invisible while leaving its children intact.